# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '39'

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code to make a directory on particular conditions.

```
def create_analysis_folder(self, analysis_id, has_headers):

        path = None
        if not os.path.exists(analysis_id):
            os.makedirs(analysis_id)    
        os.chdir(analysis_id)
        if has_headers == False:
            path = os.getcwd() + '/html'
            return path
        else:
            os.makedirs('html')
            os.chdir('html')
            shutil.copy("../../RequestURL.js", os.getcwd()) 
            return os.getcwd()
```

Upon execution this gives me an error in line

`os.makedirs(analysis_id)`

The error says `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '39'`. But I am in the processor creating a directory then why am I getting an error like this.

Comment: It seems your 'analysis_id' is number. Try converting it in string

Comment: What is the traceback? Don't use `chdir`, after executing `create_analysis_folder` you never know, in which directory you are actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `chdir` as I already stated in my comment. Here's what happens:

```
>>> os.makedirs('a/b/c') # create some directories
>>> os.chdir('a/b/c') # change into this directory
>>> os.rmdir('../c') # remove the current directory
>>> os.makedirs('z') # trying to create a directory in a non-existing directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'z'
```

The correct way, to handle such a problem is:

```
BASE_DIR = os.getcwd() # or any other path you want to work with
def create_analysis_folder(self, analysis_id, has_headers):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, analysis_id)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,analysis_id))
    path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, analysis_id, 'html')
    if has_headers:
        os.makedirs(path)
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "RequestURL.js"), path) 
    return path
```